# How can you pull data from an API to be used in Opera Mini?

Tags: javascript, api, request, opera-mini

Opera Mini has no support for the `request api`, what are the alternative ways of requesting a response from APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). There are various libraries that aim to simplify working with AJAX but you can also use it without any library.

[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

[jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks, accepted as the correct answer because I think you're right... Opera mini does support XMLHttpRequest